# How get all infomation about deployed REST services in Glassfish admin console?

Tags: java, rest, glassfish, jersey, jax-ws

If I annotate some class with `@WebService` compile and deploy it into glassfish. I can go to admin console find my class click to "View Endpoint" link and get all necessary information about service. How I can do that with Jersey? I have class with `@Path` annotation, and methods with `@Produces`, `@Post`, `@Get` etc. annotations. Where I can find information about all these methods in glassfish? Where find a link with generated wadl file?

Answer (score 0):

If you have a simple project, e.g., the `WADLTest` and you have two simple classes:

```
package net.paulvargas.test;

import javax.ws.rs.ApplicationPath;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Application;

@ApplicationPath("resources")
public class RESTConfig extends Application {

}
```

And:

```
package net.paulvargas.test;

import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;

@Path("test")
public class Test {

    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
    public String message() {
        return "Hello world!";
    }

}
```

You can find the WADL file in:

```
http://localhost:8080/WADLTest/resources/application.wadl
```

ie:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<application xmlns="http://wadl.dev.java.net/2009/02">
    <doc xmlns:jersey="http://jersey.java.net/" jersey:generatedBy="Jersey: 1.11.1 03/31/2012 06:49 PM"/>
    <grammars/>
    <resources base="http://localhost:8080/WADLTest/resources/">
        <resource path="test">
            <method id="message" name="GET">
                <response>
                    <representation mediaType="text/plain"/>
                </response>
            </method>
        </resource>
    </resources>
</application>
```

Note: for this example, does not require any extra configuration file, even not the `web.xml`. Well, that if you use Java EE 6 or Java EE 7. I'm using GlassFish Server Open Source Edition 3.1.2.2 (build 5) and Java build 1.7.0_25-b16